# is division by infinity a NaN in java?

Tags: java, android, nan

I have been having a lot of problems with NaN values propagating in a very long program I am having to look after. After much single stepping I have been able to find that at some point there is a variable whose value is shown by the Debugger as `Infinity`, there is another variable that gets divided by this Infinity variable, which results in NaN. Is this behaviour correct, or should it have resulted in 0? All the variables are `double` variables.

Comment: Did you try doing this yourself? It seems trivial to test. (Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2 for a definitive answer though.)

Comment: so the oracle docs page says it should be 0, so does this mean my NaN is not coming from the line of code where division by infinity is occuring?

Comment: That's up to you to diagnose. You haven't shown us any code, or any kind of diagnosis which has led you to this conclusion.

Comment: ok I finally realized it is doing a division of Infinity by Infinity, which is why NaN is occuring. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is division by infinity a NaN in java?

The short answer is No.

The Java Language Specification ([JLS 15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)) says:

> *"Division of a finite value by an infinity results in a signed zero."*

It also mentions that this is "determined by the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic".
The only case where division by infinity gives a NaN is when you divide an infinity by an infinity.  (Same reference as above.)

---

If you (really) see differently, then there is a bug in your Java "platform"<sup>1</sup>.  But that would be an extraordinary thing, so you need to check your evidence and methodology *really thoroughly* before calling "bug".

<sup>1 - ... most likely in the floating point *hardware*!</sup>

Comment: yes you are right, it wasn't just any number divided by infinity, but infinity divided by infinity which caused the NaN

Answer (score 1):

Think about the nature of division.

```
4/5
```

Means you've got four of something, and you're splitting it into 5 pieces. The outcome is the size of one of those pieces.

```
4/infinity
```

Means you've got four of something, and you're splitting it into infinitely small pieces. It can never be `0` because numbers are `continuous`, ergo it's `NaN` because you never stop handing out those pieces of `4`, to measure one of those pieces.

Comment: I know your pain brother.. Definite integrals are burnt onto my brain, no matter how much I drink.

Comment: but x/infinity is considered 0 isn't it? for example, when we do x/(1/0), isn't it considered to be 0?

Comment: but you are probably right, as the java debugger is showing a value of NaN for my number divided by Infinity expression

Comment: I think it's safer to return NaN instead of 0 in that specific case. You should check yourself before doing a division...

Comment: Again, in a comment to my question above, there is link to oracle docs, which clearly says `Division of a finite value by an infinity results in a signed zero. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.`

Comment: (1/0) results in an ArithmeticException: / by zero. (4/infty) is 0 in Java. Try it out, it's the way it works. What you should check before calculations and what you return in special cases depends on you business logic. There is no general "best" solution.